# Modify behaviour of vim autoindent

Tags: vim, auto-indent

In general, I like vim's autoindent feature. However, there is one thing that annoys me. When I start a list in markdown and the line hits the right margin, vim starts a new line *with a bullet marker*.

Current behavior:

```
Here is a list:

 * The first sentence goes on and on and on and on and eventually
 * it hits the right margin. I then hit Enter:
 * And another bullet appears.
```

Desired behavior:

```
Here is a list:

 * The first sentence goes on and on and on and on and eventually
   it hits the right margin. I then hit Enter:
 * And another bullet appears.
```

I would like vim to be clever enough not to insert a bullet when the line gets wrapped automatically, but instead add two spaces. Insert a bullet only if I hit enter.

Is this possible?

Comment: What plugin do you use? Plain vim does not have special indents for markdown.

Comment: No plugin (unless there is something pre-installed with Ubuntu). If I remove .vimrc and .vim and set `textwidth=75` and `autoindent` then the above described behavior happens. I do not want a plugin, I am happy as I am now *except* for this one little thing. Also, it does not depend on the file type I edit (nor would I want it to!).

Comment: `set fo-=c` Also read `:h 'formatoptions'` and `:h 'comments'`

Comment: Ah. Now I get it, of course *comments*. OK, so I can have either fish or the aquarium: if I set `formatoptions-=c` then other comments will not be automatically auto wrapped. Still, better than nothing, thank you!

Comment: Wow, it works exactly as intended, thank you.

Comment: Use autocommand. Kind of `autocmd FileType markdown setlocal comments=`